# Writing Spark DataFrame to Kafka is ignoring the partition column and kafka.partitioner.class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am trying to write a Spark DF (batch DF) to Kafka and i need to write the data to specific partitions.

I tried the following code

```
myDF.write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaProps.getBootstrapServers)
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL")
  .option("kafka.truststore.location", kafkaProps.getTrustStoreLocation)
  .option("kafka.truststore.password", kafkaProps.getTrustStorePassword)
  .option("kafka.keystore.location", kafkaProps.getKeyStoreLocation)
  .option("kafka.keystore.password", kafkaProps.getKeyStorePassword)
  .option("kafka.partitioner.class", "util.MyCustomPartitioner")
  .option("topic",kafkaProps.getTopicName)
  .save()
```

And the Schema of the DF i am writing is

```
+---+---------+-----+
|key|partition|value|
+---+---------+-----+
+---+---------+-----+
```

I had to repartition (to 1 partition) the "myDF" since i need to order the data based on date column.

It is writing the data to a Single partition but not the one that is in the DF's "partition" column or the one returned by the Custom Partitioner (which is same as the value in the partition column).

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature to use the column "partition" in your Dataframe is only available with version 3.x and not earlier according to the [2.4.7 docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka)

However, using the option `kafka.partitioner.class` will still work. Spark Structured Streaming allows you to use plain KafkaConsumer configuration when using the prefix `kafka.`, so this will also work on version 2.4.4.

Below code runs fine with Spark 3.0.1 and Confluent community edition 5.5.0. On Spark 2.4.4, the "partition" column does not have any impact, but my custom partitioner class applies.

```scala
case class KafkaRecord(partition: Int, value: String)

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("test")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()


// create DataFrame
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq((0, "Alice"), (1, "Bob")).toDF("partition", "value").as[KafkaRecord]

df.write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("topic", "test")
  .save()
```

What you then see in the console-consumer:

```
# partition 0
$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic test --partition 0
Alice
```

and

```
# partition 1
$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic test --partition 1
Bob
```

---

Also getting the same results when using a custom `Partitioner`

```scala
.option("kafka.partitioner.class", "org.test.CustomPartitioner")
```

where my custom Partitioner is defined as

```scala
package org.test
class CustomPartitioner extends Partitioner {

  override def partition(topic: String, key: Any, keyBytes: Array[Byte], value: Any,valueBytes: Array[Byte],cluster: Cluster): Int = {
    if (!valueBytes.isEmpty && valueBytes.map(_.toChar).mkString == "Bob") {
      0
    } else {
      1
    }
  }
}
```